# Deeplinking issue in my app

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

I want to open my app when open this url (for ex: https://www.google.com)
When i have open that url in browser then i can't get any option to open your app.

I have implemented this code for deeplinking in manifest activity tag.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data
           android:host="www.google.com"
           android:scheme="http" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
 </intent-filter>
```

But why it's not working. If there is any mistake from my side then please tell me.

I have done lots of googling for this but can't find any issue in my code.

Comment: How are you reading it in OnCreate? When you say its not working? Is it throwing any error?

Comment: @AmodGokhale but not getting option to open my app . then how to check oncreate or etc?

Comment: Please add your pathPrefix, path and pathPattern.

Comment: And what are you using for Deep linking like firebase or branch.

Comment: branch..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:autoVerify="true"
```

This is used for [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html).
The system will check if the app is authorized to handle such url by parsing the file located at https://www.google.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json.

Since you are not google, you're not authorized to use App Links method to google's urls.
These urls might already be catched by google's own apps (which are defined in that same file).

Comment: i have checked this url also.but can't get any option for select my app
 <data
                    android:host="www.flickr.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/photos/"
                    android:scheme="http" />

Comment: again, you must own the domain name you're trying to use AppLinks on, and put this file with your app info.

Comment: which file you are talking about?

Comment: assetlinks.json

Comment: where i have to place this file? in my android code? but where?

Comment: Read the documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot .you save my time.. thank you very much.

Comment: hello for both debug and release have different "assetlinks.json" file to generate on server?

Comment: If your app uses the same package name, you can add multiple fingerprints to the files, otherwise, you must add another object at the root (like the google's one)